# do-release-upgrade stalled

Tags: server, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I am in the middle of a `do-release-upgrade` 10.04 to 12.04 server but it appears to have stalled while upgrading `mysql`

```
Configuration file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** my.cnf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? n
Setting up adduser (3.113ubuntu2) ...
Installing new version of config file /etc/deluser.conf ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 180718 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (from .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.41-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
```

With no progress for 40 minutes.

The logs in `/var/log/dist-upgrade` show no other indication of errors.

Can anyone recommend best next step?